# Why am I getting this error? "signal: illegal instruction (core dumped)"

Tags: c, runtime-error, function-definition

I am working on a program that is a simulation of a job scheduler for an operating system.The scheduler will read in a list of jobs with the relevant information and output the order of completion along with the time of completion for each job and other relevant statistics. I am using replit to compile this c code and I'm and getting the (core dumped) error and I am not sure why or what this really means. I'm relatively new to c code so any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void program1(int *id, int *arrival, int *cpuBurst);
int *program2(int *id, int *arrival, int *cpuBurst, int *enter);
int program3(int *id, int *arrival, int  *cpuBurst, int *enter);

int main() {

   int id[7] = {
      100,
      101,
      102,
      103,
      104,
      105,
      106
   };
   int arrival[7] = {
      0,
      6,
      8,
      12,
      19,
      30,
      35
   };
   int cpuBurst[7] = {
      10,
      10,
      4,
      20,
      15,
      5,
      10
   };

   int enter[7] = {
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0,
      0
   };

   program1(id, arrival, cpuBurst);
   int *ptr = program2(id, arrival, cpuBurst, enter);
   int loop = program3(id, arrival, cpuBurst, enter);

   return 0;
}

/************************** PROGRAM 1 ****************************/
void program1(int *id, int *arrival, int *cpuBurst) {
   int completion[7];
   int enter[7];
   float att;
   float art;
   int time = 0;
   int loop = 1;
   while (loop > 0) {
      printf("FIRST COME FIRST SERVE\n");
      for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
         if (arrival[i] <= time) {
            enter[i] = time;
            while (cpuBurst[i] > 0) {
               cpuBurst[i] = cpuBurst[i] - 1;
               time = time + 1;
            }
         }
         if (cpuBurst[i] == 0) {
            completion[i] = time;

            printf("%s %d %s %d\n", "Id: ", id[i], " Completion: ", completion[i]);
         } else {
            loop = loop + 1;
         }
      }
      loop = loop - 1;
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      att = att + completion[j] - arrival[j];
   }
   att = att / 7;
   printf("Average turnaround time: %f\n", att);
   for (int r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
      art = art + enter[r] - arrival[r];
   }
   art = art / 7;
   printf("Average response time: %f\n", art);
}

/************************** PROGRAM 2 ************************************/
int *program2(int *id, int *arrival, int *cpuBurst, int *enter) {
   int completion[7];
   float att;
   float art;
   int time = 0;
   int temp;
   int timeCheck(int hey, int yuh[], int sup[]);
   int go(int yuh, int oof);

   printf("SHORTEST JOB FRIST\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      temp = timeCheck(time, arrival, cpuBurst);
      enter[temp] = time;
      while (cpuBurst[temp] > 0) {
         cpuBurst[temp] = cpuBurst[temp] - 1;
         time = time + 1;
      }
      cpuBurst[temp] = 20000;
      completion[temp] = time;
      printf("%s %d %s %d\n", "Id: ", id[temp], " Completion: ", completion[temp]);
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      att = att + completion[j] - arrival[j];
   }
   att = att / 7;
   printf("Average turnaround time: %f\n", att);
   for (int r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
      art = art + enter[r] - arrival[r];
   }
   art = art / 7;
   printf("Average response time: %f\n", art);
}

int go(int time, int arrival) {
   if (time >= arrival) {
      return 1;
   } else return 0;
}

int timeCheck(int time, int ar[], int burst[]) {
   int *ptr;
   *ptr = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      if (ar[i] <= time) {
         if (burst[i] < burst[ * ptr]) {
            *ptr = i;
         }
      }
   }
   return *ptr;
}

/************************************ PROGRAM 3 *********************************/
int program3(int *id, int *arrival, int *cpuBurst, int *enter) {
   float att;
   float art;
   int time = 0;
   int completion[7];
   int hey = 0;
   int checker = 1;
   int check(int yo[]);

   printf("ROUND ROBIN\n");
   while (checker > 0) {
      if (7 == hey) {
         hey = 0;
      }
      for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
         if (cpuBurst[hey] == 0) {
            break;
         }
         if (enter[hey] == 0) {
            enter[hey] = time;
         }
         cpuBurst[hey] -= 1;
         if (cpuBurst[hey] > 0) {
            time = time + 1;
         }
      }
      if (cpuBurst[hey] == 0) {
         completion[hey] = time;
         printf("%s %d %s %d\n", "Id: ", id[hey], " Completion: ", completion[hey]);
      }
      hey = hey + 1;
      checker = check(cpuBurst);
   }
   for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      att = att + completion[j] - arrival[j];
   }
   att = att / 7;
   printf("Average turnaround time: %f\n", att);
   for (int r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
      art = art + enter[r] - arrival[r];
   }
   art = art / 7;
   printf("Average response time: %f\n", art);
}
int check(int burst[]) {
   int loop = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      if (burst[i] == 0) {
         continue;
      } else loop++;
   }
   return loop;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 make -s
 ./main
FIRST COME FIRST SERVE
Id:  100  Completion:  10
Id:  101  Completion:  20
Id:  102  Completion:  24
Id:  103  Completion:  44
Id:  104  Completion:  59
Id:  105  Completion:  64
Id:  106  Completion:  74
Average turnaround time: nan
Average response time: nan
SHORTEST JOB FRIST
signal: illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Comment: You can use a debugger like GDB to step through your code line by line to find the error.

Your error lies inside the `time_check` function. You have a pointer `ptr` which is never properly initialized resulting in undefined behaviour. Either make it an integer or set it properly to an address that you can access.

Answer (score 0):

At least in this function

```
int timeCheck(int time, int ar[], int burst[]) {
   int *ptr;
   *ptr = 0;
   //...
```

you are dereferencing a pointer that was not initialized and has an indeterminate value that results in undefined behavior.

There is no any need to use the pointer of the type `int *` instead of an object of the type `int` within the function.

Pay attention to that for example the functions `program2` and  `program3` return nothing though their return types are not `void`.

Or within the function `program2` there is declared function `go`

```
int go(int yuh, int oof);
```

but it is not used within the function `program2`.

Comment: How would I properly initialize that pointer?

Comment: @eseazywork As I wrote in my answer there is no any need to use a pointer within the function. Use an object of the type int.